# Django app on heroku doesn't load staticfiles from S3 bucket

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

When I run `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` it does upload staticfiles to AWS S3, however when I run django in production, my static files do not load to the page.[image]

To be honest i dont know why do i have bad request, since i already did collectstatic to S3.
My AWS settings @ settings.py

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
STATIC_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'

AWS_URL = os.environ.get('AWS_URL')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATIC_URL = "https://" + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + ".s3.amazonaws.com/"
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: Have you configured your bucket to serve the items publicly?

Comment: oh lord. that was the case, kind of. I made a typo in a bucketlist policy bucket name.. thanks for pointing me to the right direction